# What is wrong with adding a row to pandas dataframe like this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a simple dataframe like the following.

```
cache_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ticker', 'maturity', 'rate', 'datetime'])
cache_df = cache_df.set_index(['ticker', 'maturity'])
```

When I try to add a row, i am getting an error that i couldnt wrap my mind around. Can anyone help me understand why?

```
cache_df.loc[symbolName, expiry] = [rate, updateTime]
```

I got

> ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a
>   different length than the value

and my dataframe looks strange after the error message.

```
Out[106]: 
                rate datetime  2016-11-18 00:00:00
ticker maturity                                   
GECC             NaN      NaN                  NaN
```

if I do

```
cache_df.loc[[1,2]] = [3,4]
```

I get a different error:

> ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has
>   no identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after spending nearly two hours googling for possible causes, I figured out why. The problem is with multi-indexing. I guess a more helpful error message could be used here.

With a multi-indexed dataframe, the loc needs to be explicit.

The following code solves the issue.

```
cache_df.loc[(symbolName, expiry), :] = [rate, updateTime]
```